# Exclude parent pom plugin dependency in child pom

Tags: maven

Maven plugin and its dependency defined in parent pom and I do not want my child pom to include that plugin dependency.

For example, if there is 1 parent and 100 children, 99 use that plugin and want to exclude that plugin in one child.

How could we achieve this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struggling with Maven parent/child plugin configuration inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648556/struggling-with-maven-parent-child-plugin-configuration-inheritance)

Comment: You may find this useful: [Is there anyway to exclude artifacts inherited from a parent POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681759/is-there-anyway-to-exclude-artifacts-inherited-from-a-parent-pom).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. In parent pom, we should include child details as in below to remove this plugin dependency in child.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExclude>${child-dependency-groupId}:${child-dependency-artifactId}</classpathDependencyExclude>
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment/question edit, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring the plugin in `<plugins>` section, you should do the job in `<pluginManagement>`

see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management for more details