# maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack Unable to find/resolve artifact

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

## [SOLVED] How to fix: maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack Unable to find/resolve artifact.

After a day of trial and error, I realized something. The maven plugins are trying to build the parent module (rst_bav). This module is just a container declaring dependencies and maven plugins. I never intended it to be built.

Therefore the solution is to move all plugin declarations to the child modules (rst_eureka, rst_admin, rst_mail, rst_config) and remove them from the parent module (rst_bav).

There is also an answer [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924634/define-maven-plugins-in-parent-pom-but-only-invoke-plugins-in-child-projects). Matts had the same problem as me and wrote a plugin to orchestrate plugin execution for maven child modules, while the plugins themselves are declared in the parent module. I did not try said plugin though.

---

---

## Original Question

I am trying to package a multi module maven project. During the package phase, all dependecies shall be unpacked into the /target/dependencies/ directory, so that I can build a docker image as described here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

My multi module maven project looks like this:

```
rst_bav         (packaging="pom")
 |_ rst_eureka  (packaging="jar")
 |_ rst_admin   (packaging="jar")
 |_ rst_mail    (packaging="jar")
 |_ rst_config  (packaging="jar")
```

**The build fails on trying to unpack rst_bav, saying it does not exist in the local nexus.**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\git\rst_bav "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=60959:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.3.2 clean install package -e -U
Console output is saving to: C:\tmp\indea.log
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] rst_bav                                                            [pom]
[INFO] rst_eureka                                                         [jar]
[INFO] rst_admin                                                          [jar]
[INFO] rst_mail                                                           [jar]
[INFO] rst_config                                                         [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< de.hhpv:rst_bav >---------------------------
[INFO] Building rst_bav 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                    [1/5]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ rst_bav ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\git\rst_bav\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ rst_bav ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack (unpack) @ rst_bav ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: de.hhpv:rst_bav:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:jar
Downloading from archetype: http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/de/hhpv/rst_bav/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central-repo: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/hhpv/rst_bav/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from internal-repository: http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/repository/maven-public/de/hhpv/rst_bav/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from internal-repository: http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/repository/maven-public/de/hhpv/rst_bav/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rst_bav-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading from central-repo: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/hhpv/rst_bav/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rst_bav-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading from archetype: http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/de/hhpv/rst_bav/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rst_bav-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for rst_bav 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] rst_bav ............................................ FAILURE [ 20.525 s]
[INFO] rst_eureka ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] rst_admin .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] rst_mail ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] rst_config ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.973 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-03T15:32:45+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack (unpack) on project rst_bav: Unable to find/resolve artifact.: Could not find artifact de.hhpv:rst_bav:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in internal-repository (http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/repository/maven-public) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack (unpack) on project rst_bav: Unable to find/resolve artifact.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to find/resolve artifact.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (UnpackMojo.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.doExecute (UnpackMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.ArtifactResolverException: Could not find artifact de.hhpv:rst_bav:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in internal-repository (http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/repository/maven-public)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (UnpackMojo.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.doExecute (UnpackMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact de.hhpv:rst_bav:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in internal-repository (http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/repository/maven-public)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (UnpackMojo.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.doExecute (UnpackMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact de.hhpv:rst_bav:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in internal-repository (http://nexus.hh.hhpv.dir:8081/repository/maven-public)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems (UnpackMojo.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.doExecute (UnpackMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**rst_bav/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.hhpv</groupId>
    <artifactId>rst_bav</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>rst_bav</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <revision>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin-version>3.1.1</maven-dependency-plugin-version>
        <spring-boot-maven-plugin-version>${spring-boot-version}</spring-boot-maven-plugin-version>

        <spring-cloud-version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud-version>
        <spring-boot-version>2.0.5.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
        <!-- newest version 2.1.2-SNAPSHOT does not work with current spring boot (reactor libraries vs tomcat) -->
        <spring-boot-admin-server-version>2.0.4</spring-boot-admin-server-version>

        <javax-version>2.0.3</javax-version>
        <javax-activation-version>javax.activation</javax-activation-version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>rst_eureka</module>
        <module>rst_admin</module>
        <module>rst_mail</module>
        <module>rst_config</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Cloud -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--
            This plugin unpacks the dependencies and jar file during mvn package
            Based on this article:
            https://openliberty.io/blog/2018/07/02/creating-dual-layer-docker-images-for-spring-boot-apps.html
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <!--
                            dependency:unpack always downloads artifacts to default local repository first, and then
                            unpacks the artifacts to the desired locations. For large size unique snapshot artifacts,
                            the downloads can quickly fill up default local repository, and therefore local disk, after
                            many executions. To clean up the downloaded artifacts as part the build, set
                            localRepositoryDirectory's value to a location in your project's target directory.

                            https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html
                            -->
                            <localRepositoryDirectory>${project.build.directory}/localrepo</localRepositoryDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a problem with your proxy configuration in your IDE

Does your company use a specific proxy ?

Check your maven user settings path in your IDE and be sure the proxy in the settings.xml is right