# NoSuchElementException thrown while Testing Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to test my maven plugin using the [*maven plugin testing harness*](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html). The only documentation I can find on the matter is rather old, and I have found [**similar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779351/component-lookup-exception-with-org-apache-maven-repository-repositorysystem-in) threads with the same error, but no resolution, at least not one that solves the problem for me. The error can be boiled down to a *NoSuchElementException* being thrown when trying to run the *lookupMojo* method.

Has anyone else experience this or a similar issue, and how did you fix it? Let me know if you need any more information and I will post updates.

**Plugin Class**

```
@Mojo(name = "my_plugin", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.CLEAN, threadSafe = true)
public class MyPlugin extends AbstractMojo
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyPlugin.class);

    @Parameter private String configFileLocation;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        logger.info("The config file location is: {}", configFileLocation);
        saveSystemProperties(new File(configFileLocation));
    }

    private void saveSystemProperties(final File file)
    {
        logger.info("Attempting to save system properties");
        try(FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file))
        {
            System.getProperties().store(fr, "Properties");
            logger.info("Properties successfully saved. Closing File Output Stream Implicitly");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            logger.info("There was an IO error. ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Plugin Test Class**

```
public class MyPluginTester extends AbstractMojoTestCase
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyPluginTester.class);

    protected void setup() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testMojoGoal() throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("Loading Test Pom File");
        File testPom = new File(getBasedir(),"src/test/resources/pom/basic-test-plugin-config.xml");
        assertNotNull(testPom);
        MyPlugin mojo = (LittleSysStore)lookupMojo("configure", testPom);
        assertNotNull(mojo);
    }
}
```

**POM File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.plugin.annotations.version>3.5</maven.plugin.annotations.version>
        <maven.plugin.testing.version>3.3.0</maven.plugin.testing.version>
        <maven.version>3.5.0</maven.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.annotations.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.testing.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Output**

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
  roleHint: com.my.stuff-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:clean
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusTestCase.lookup(PlexusTestCase.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.lookupMojo(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.lookupMojo(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:355)
    at unit_tests.LittleSysStoreTest.testMojoGoal(LittleSysStoreTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: How does your MyPluginTester know about that method? Does AbstractMojoTestCase class contain the method called lookupMojo? Perhaps the method is private instead of public?

Comment: correct. AbstractMojoTestCase is a class included in the org.apache.maven.plugin.testing package. It should contain everything necessary to perform the test, or so it seams according to the linked docs.

Comment: they really are, and from what I have gathered searching this problem, it is a common issue and without a documented resolution

Comment: try calling it with the string, string parameters just to see if the library knows of the other method declaration available?

Comment: Immediately threw a file not found exception. let me tinker around with the path and I will get back to you.

Comment: Note it says this in the java docs "TODO: add a way to use the plugin POM for the lookup so that the user doesn't have to provide the a:g:v:goal as the role hint for the mojo lookup." perhaps you have to use the lookupMojo(String groupId, String artifactId, String version, String goal, org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.PlexusConfiguration pluginConfiguration) method declaration and the others were never implemented... good luck

Comment: this did not help, it is throwing the exact same exception unfortunately

Comment: try using the double string argument but use the absolute path of the File you are trying to use in the lookup. It shouldn't throw a file not found exception if the correct path is used.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my last comment. I tried all variations of the lookupMojo method, including the double string arguments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having wasted an hour reading their dreadful documentation, I took a look at the harness test suite. Try using the following:

```
   void testStuff() throws Exception {
        File testPom = new File(getBasedir(),"src/test/resources/pom/basic-test-plugin-config.xml");
        assertNotNull(testPom);
        MyPlugin mojo = new MyPlugin();
        mojo = (MyPlugin) configureMojo(
            mojo, extractPluginConfiguration("cue-maven-plugin", testPom
        );
        mojo.execute();
    }
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: It works, but won't inject @Parameter for some reason. For example MavenProject won't be injected.

Comment: @AndreyRodionov I found a solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523947/1744774.

Comment: Seems the latest version, it get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following `maven-plugin` project that runs an "unitegration" test named `testLiveWithPOM()` (i.e. a Surefire/JUnit test with a live plugin resolution from the local Maven repository) successfully. The key ideas are to suppress Surefire's `<execution>/<id>default-test` and to run it after `<default-install>` using [`maven-invoker`](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/apidocs/index.html). Perhaps this could also be implemented with the [Maven Invoker Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/).

#### my-maven-plugin/pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>igb</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>My Maven Plugin with Surefire tests</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.version>3.6.3</maven.version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>${maven.version}</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- needed when injecting the Maven Project into a plugin -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- use latest plugins rather than Maven's defaults -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_maven-plugin_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- From: How to override default binding to phase of a Maven plugin <https://stackoverflow.com/q/13250377/1744774> -->
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-test</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- 
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                -->

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-help-mojo</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- From: How to override default binding to phase of a Maven plugin <https://stackoverflow.com/q/13250377/1744774> -->
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-after-install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

#### ValidateMojo

```java
package name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;

@Mojo( name = "validate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.VALIDATE )
public class ValidateMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    private final Log log = getLog();

    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true )
    private MavenProject project;

    @Parameter
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {

        log.debug( "message:\n  " + message + ".execute()..." );
        log.debug( "project:\n  " + project );

    } // execute()

} // ValidateMojo
```

#### ValidateMojoTest

```java
package name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins;

import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.InvocationResult;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ValidateMojoTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ValidateMojoTest.class );

    private final Path pom = Path.of( getBasedir(), "src/test/resources/my-maven-plugin-test/pom.xml" );

    @Test
    public void testPOM() throws Exception {

        log.debug( "\n  Using POM '...{}'.", pom.toString().substring( getBasedir().length() ) );

        assertNotNull( pom );
        assertTrue( pom.toFile().exists() );
    }

    @Test
    public void testLiveWithPOM() throws Exception {

        log.debug( "\n  Live testing my plugin's validate goal ..." );
        out.println( new String( new char[80] ).replace( "\0", "#" ) );

        final InvocationResult result = MavenInvoker.invoke( pom, List.of( "validate" ) /*, Debug.TRUE*/ );

        out.println( new String( new char[80] ).replace( "\0", "#" ) );

        if ( result.getExitCode() != 0 )
            throw new MavenInvocationException(
                String.format( "MavenInvoker.invoke() failed with exit code %n.", result.getExitCode() ),
                result.getExecutionException() );
    }

} // ValidateMojoTest
```

#### MavenInvoker

```java
package name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvocationRequest;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.InvocationRequest;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.InvocationResult;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException;

/** A helper class to invoke Maven. Handy for testing self-written plugins.
 *
 * @author Gerold "Geri" Broser <https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744774/gerold-broser>
 */
public class MavenInvoker {

    public enum Debug {

        FALSE( false ),
        TRUE( true );

        private final boolean debug;

        Debug( final boolean debug ) {
            this.debug = debug;
        }

        boolean value() {
            return debug;
        }

    } // Debug

    /**
     * @param pom The POM to be used when invoking Maven.
     * @param phasesAndGoals The lifecycle phases and plugin goals to invoke. See <a href="https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference">Lifecycle Reference</a>.
     * @param debug Optional parameter. Default: {@link Debug}{@code .FALSE}. Set it to {@link Debug}{@code .TRUE} to run Maven in debug mode (like {@code mvn -X ...}).
     * @return The {@link InvocationResult} of the invocation.
     * @throws MavenInvocationException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static InvocationResult invoke( final Path pom, final List<String> phasesAndGoals, final Debug... debug )
        throws MavenInvocationException, IOException {

        return invoke( pom, phasesAndGoals, System.getProperties(), debug );
    } // invoke()

    /**
     * @param pom The POM to be used when invoking Maven.
     * @param phasesAndGoals The lifecycle phases and plugin goals to invoke. See <a href="https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference">Lifecycle Reference</a>.
     * @param properties Unused yet, since it causes a message "The command line is too long.".
     * @param debug Optional parameter. Default: {@link Debug}{@code .FALSE}. Set it to {@link Debug}{@code .TRUE} to run Maven in debug mode (like {@code mvn -X ...}).
     * @return The {@link InvocationResult} of the invocation.
     * @throws MavenInvocationException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static InvocationResult invoke( final Path pom, final List<String> phasesAndGoals, final Properties properties,
        final Debug... debug )
        throws MavenInvocationException, IOException {

        // From: How to run Maven from Java? <https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534306/1744774>
        final InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest()
            .setPomFile( pom.toFile() )
            .setGoals( phasesAndGoals )
            .setDebug( debug.length > 0 ? debug[0].value() : false )
            .setBatchMode( true );
        //.setProperties( properties ); // Causes message: "The command line is too long." (?!?)

        // Not necessary here since ignored with Batch Mode.
        //From: How to solve Maven Invoker API warning: Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured
        //      <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60803155/1744774>
        //try ( InputStream nis = InputStream.nullInputStream() ) {
        //  request.setInputStream( nis );
        //}

        return new DefaultInvoker().execute( request );
    } // invoke()

} // MavenInvoker
```

#### my-maven-plugin/src/test/resources/my-maven-plugin-test/pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>igb</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>my-maven-plugin</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>validate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <message>my-maven-plugin:validate</message>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

#### `.../my-maven-plugin $ mvn clean install`

```text
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ my-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Installing D:\_dev\eclipse.wksp.se\my-maven-plugin\target\my-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to D:\.m2\igb\my-maven-plugin\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\my-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\_dev\eclipse.wksp.se\my-maven-plugin\pom.xml to D:\.m2\igb\my-maven-plugin\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\my-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (test-after-install) @ my-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins.ValidateMojoTest
00:03:22.200 [main] DEBUG name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins.ValidateMojoTest - 
  Using POM '...\src\test\resources\my-maven-plugin-test\pom.xml'.
00:03:22.296 [main] DEBUG name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins.ValidateMojoTest - 
  Live testing my plugin's validate goal ...
################################################################################
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< igb:my-maven-plugin-test >----------------------
[INFO] Building my-maven-plugin-test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- my-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:validate (my-maven-plugin) @ my-maven-plugin-test ---
[debug] message:
  my-maven-plugin:validate.execute()...
[debug] project:
  MavenProject: igb:my-maven-plugin-test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\_dev\eclipse.wksp.se\my-maven-plugin\src\test\resources\my-maven-plugin-test\pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.188 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-02T00:03:23+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
################################################################################
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.074 s - in name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins.ValidateMojoTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.908 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-02T00:03:23+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As mentioned at the beginning this could be done with the [Maven Invoker Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/), as well. But its output ist just:

```text
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.2.1:integration-test (test-after-install) @ my-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Building: pom.xml
[INFO]           pom.xml .......................................... SUCCESS (1.9 s)
```

No build steps output, no log output, not even in the created `.../target/its/build.log`:

```text
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----< name.broser.gerold.maven.plugins:my-maven-plugin-test >-----
[INFO] Building my-maven-plugin-test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.082 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-05T14:01:06+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```