# Execute maven assembly plugin only on child POMs

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project with a parent POM and three child projects with.I want to execute the goal assembly:assembly only on one child POM. I already read the following post, but I didn't get it to work with the maven assembly plugin.

[Execute Maven plugin goal on child modules, but not on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625492/execute-maven-plugin-goal-on-child-modules-but-not-on-parent)

If I run

```
mvn -DskipTests=true assembly:assembly
```

I get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) on project inhouse: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]

It seems that it always parses the plugin configuration and looks for the assembly descriptor, even then, if I do not  put the plugin into the parent POM at all. Has anyone a solution for the assembly plugin?

Comment: FYI, `assembly:assembly` is [deprecated](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html).  Use `assembly:single` instead.  Also, the latest assembly plugin is version 2.4, sometimes a version upgrade contains bug fixes that might help.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can configure in the aggregation `pom.xml` the assembly plugin to skip execution.

In `<build><plugins>` section

```
<configuration><skip>true</skip></configuration>
```

Comment: I have this in my parent POM, but I still get the error "No assembly descriptors found.": <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                   <skip>true</skip>
                 </configuration>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <id>assembly</id>
                         <phase>package</phase>
                     </execution>
                 </executions>
             </plugin>

Comment: Where does the assembly file exist? If you are referencing it using property substitution it might be in the wrong location. If you post the structure of your multi-module project and the location of the assembly I can probably figure it out for you.

Comment: **The good answer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24214396/1667004)** `<skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>` **

Answer (score 11):

the rigth option is : `<skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>` in order to skip the parent project.

Answer (score 2):

you can define in parent pom properties

```
<assembly.skipAssembly>true</assembly.skipAssembly>
```

and overwritte this property in your module pom properties

```
<assembly.skipAssembly>false</assembly.skipAssembly>
```